# How to send a message from an Activity to a Service both in Separate APKs

Tags: android

I am making a background service that is basically a watchdog for a task that should remain on the screen at all times.   The watchdog application will restart the main application when it crashes.  It will also update the main application when an update is available (the apk is downloaded over HTTP).  For this reason the watchdog application and the main application are in separate apks.

I have tried registering intents in the manifest, with IntentFilters, and so on (I don't have access to the MainApplication.class), but can't seem to get the message through from the Activity to the Service.  I am almost to the point of using the filesystem for messaging, but thought I would ask here.

Thanks!

Comment: "but can't seem to get the message through from the Activity to the Service" -- please explain, **in detail**, what "the message" is and how you are attempting to send it.

Comment: I just want to send a string.

Comment: Intents should work..  you could also have your main activity bind to the service and send it messages via AIDL (but that's more complicated).

Comment: //Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        //sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
        //sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        //sendBroadcast(sendIntent);

Comment: I have also tried this.
        Log.d( TAG, "Sending Broadcast");
        Intent new_intent = new Intent();
        new_intent.setAction(ACTION_STRING_SERVICE);
        sendBroadcast(new_intent);

Comment: either call `Context#startService` or `Context#bindtService`, the former is easier, the latter lets you use a well defined interface (via AIDL compiler)